# How to store data

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have an app which records Insurances in a company where they work. each insurance has a time frame.

Example : Employee John decides to buy a medical insurance from their employer. But the next month john decides to change to another medical plan. John can have "n" number of plans with his employer.

i need a good way to store that database, because I need to show the John had a specific plan in a particular month. There are also some complex calculations which are involved on the times when johb changes the insurance plans

Answer (score 1):

I would create a many-to-many relationship between employees and medical plans, using a [daterange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) to identify the period in which the chosen plan was valid.

```
create table employee 
(
  id integer primary key, 
  first_name text not null,
  last_name text not null
);

create table medical_plan
(
   id integer primary key, 
   ... additional columns for the plan ....
);

create table employee_plans
(
   employee_id integer not null references employee,
   plan_id integer not null references medical_plan, 
   active_during daterange not null, 
);
```

You can prevent overlapping ranges in the assignment with [an exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION)

```
alter table employee_plans 
  add constraint non_overlapping_ranges 
  exclude using gist (employee_id with =, active_during with &&);
```

<sup>(you need to install the [btree_gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) in order to be able to create that constraint)</sup>

Then you can check which plan is active by joining the tables and adding a WHERE condition on the date range:

```
select e.*, p.*
from employee e
  join employee_plans ep on ep.employee_id = e.id
  join medical_plan mp on mp.id = ep.plan_id
where mp.active_during @> date '2019-02-01';
```

`mp.active_during @> date '2019-02-01'` means: return all rows where the specified date falls in to the range defined by `active_during`.